# Set up a global listener/controller for events triggered on document with CanJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, canjs, canjs-control

Probably not the common use case, but I have several custom events being fired on document, and the application listens for them. Example: http://jsbin.com/uradod/3/edit

How can I convert this to be CanJS controller? I was of something similar to this: http://jsbin.com/uradod/6/edit. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to non standard events by adding a whitespace before the event name. For some reason it didn't work on JSBin but here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BT95c/

```
can.Control('Events',
/** @Static */
{},{
    " sampleEvent" : function(el, ev, data)
    {
        $('body').html('Controller: ' + data.text);
    }
});

var events = new Events(document);

$(document).trigger("sampleEvent", {text:"Event trigger"});
```